# Including HTML and JSP ViewResolvers Simultaneously

Tags: java, jsp, spring-mvc

I'm trying to utilize Thymeleaf's `ServletContextTemplateResolver` as well as an `InternalViewResolver` in my application in order to resolve both `html` and `jsp` views returned in my controller. I've set the order of the Template Resolver to 0 as the resolver with the highest order is the last resolver in the chain:

```
    /** Thymeleaf HTML Template View Resolver **/
    @Bean
    public ServletContextTemplateResolver getServletContextTemplateResolver() {
        ServletContextTemplateResolver templateResolver = new ServletContextTemplateResolver();
        templateResolver.setPrefix("/WEB-INF/html/");
        templateResolver.setSuffix(".html");
        templateResolver.setTemplateMode("HTML5");
        templateResolver.setOrder(0);
        return templateResolver;

    }
    /** JSP View Resolver **/
    @Bean
    public InternalResourceViewResolver getInternalResourceViewResolver() {
        InternalResourceViewResolver resolver = new InternalResourceViewResolver();
        resolver.setPrefix("/WEB-INF/jsp/");
        resolver.setSuffix(".jsp");
        resolver.setOrder(1);
        return resolver;
    }
```

However my views are always resolved to html. Is there an additional piece of logic I can include (or maybe the resolvers aren't configured properly?) or pass to my ModelAndView objects to make sure my jsp views are mapped to the Internal View Resolver and html vies are mapped to my Template Resolver? i.e. something like `ModelAndView mav = new ModelAndView("mypage.html");` //which resolves to mypage.html.jsp of course.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For ServletContextTemplateResolver (i.e. an impl of TemplateResolver), you can specify the "pattern" for files that should be ignored by it.

Try this method: [see here for any other applicable method](http://www.thymeleaf.org/apidocs/thymeleaf/1.0.1/org/thymeleaf/templateresolver/AbstractTemplateResolver.html#setResolvablePatterns(java.util.Set))

`public void setResolvablePatterns(Set<String> resolvablePatterns)`

**UPDATE**

Looks like the ThymeLeaf Resolver to be used with Spring App is totally different:`org.thymeleaf.spring4.view.ThymeleafViewResolver`

See the bean defined here:
http://www.thymeleaf.org/doc/tutorials/2.1/thymeleafspring.html#views-and-view-resolvers-in-spring-mvc

```
<bean class="org.thymeleaf.spring4.view.ThymeleafViewResolver">
  <property name="templateEngine" ref="templateEngine" />
  <property name="order" value="1" />
  <property name="viewNames" value="*.html,*.xhtml" />
</bean>
```

Comment: Thanks @Mecon I'm trying to locate the syntax for the patterns but cannot locate a proper one. So far I've created my Set: private final `Set<String> mySet = new HashSet<String>();` and added a String pattern to it `mySet.add("/html/*)` which was just a wild guess, and finally `templateResolver.setResolvablePatterns(mySet);` but it still gets resolved as a JSP.  Any thoughts?

Comment: this pattern should be a pattern applicable to the "view names".  What are the View Names being returned by your Controller?

Comment: Ahh I see. My controller returns "mypage" as a view name for my html page: `return "mypage";`

Comment: How about..  you change this "templateResolver.setPrefix("/WEB-INF/html/");"   to:   "templateResolver.setPrefix("/WEB-INF/");  ?   And then in the Controller.. pass view name as:  "html/mypage"

Comment: ... then your pattern can be something like html/*

Comment: any luck with this issue?

Comment: I've just included the new setPrefix however my viewResolver returns `View Not Found: "/jsp/html/mypage.html.jsp"` which is pretty whacky. I'll have to dive more into the `ServletContextTemplateResolver` and the method you provided

Comment: your mypage is being attempted to be resolved by the InternalResourceViewResolver... Which means that your View Name is getting ignore by the very first Resolver...

Comment: Right that is exactly why I raised the question, the InternalResourceViewResolver takes precedence no matter the setOrder() value. I believe your method will work I just need to set it properly via the Config file, the controller or a combination of both

Comment: I updated my answer.. looks like the ThymeLeaf Resolver is not what is expected, when running in Spring App. Check out the link in the answer.

Answer (score 1):

Here's my working configuration for resolving both HTML and JSP.  You can adapt it for Javaconfig as needed.

```
  <bean id="viewResolver" class="org.thymeleaf.spring4.view.ThymeleafViewResolver">
    <property name="order" value="1" />
    <property name="characterEncoding" value="UTF-8" />
    <property name="templateEngine" ref="templateEngine" />
  </bean>

  <bean id="templateEngine" class="org.thymeleaf.spring4.SpringTemplateEngine">
    <property name="templateResolvers">
      <set>
    <ref bean="webTemplateResolver" />
    <ref bean="emailTemplateResolver" />
      </set>
    </property>
    <property name="additionalDialects">
      <set>
        <bean class="org.thymeleaf.extras.springsecurity3.dialect.SpringSecurityDialect"/>
      </set>
    </property>
  </bean>

  <bean id="webTemplateResolver" class="org.thymeleaf.templateresolver.ServletContextTemplateResolver">
    <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/thymeleaf/" />
    <property name="templateMode" value="HTML5" />
    <property name="suffix" value=".html" />
    <property name="characterEncoding" value="UTF-8" />
    <property name="cacheable" value="false" />
    <property name="order" value="3" />
  </bean>

  <bean id="emailTemplateResolver" class="org.thymeleaf.templateresolver.ClassLoaderTemplateResolver">
    <property name="prefix" value="templates/" />
    <property name="suffix" value=".html" />
    <property name="templateMode" value="HTML5" />
    <property name="characterEncoding" value="UTF-8" />
    <property name="cacheable" value="false"/>
    <property name="order" value="2" />
  </bean>

  <bean id="tilesViewResolver" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.UrlBasedViewResolver">
    <property name="order" value="0" />
    <property name="viewClass"
          value="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.tiles3.TilesView"/>
  </bean>

  <bean id="tilesConfigurer" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.tiles3.TilesConfigurer">
    <property name="definitions">
      <list>
    <value>/WEB-INF/**/views.xml</value>
      </list>
    </property>
  </bean>
```

`views.xml` contains all the definitions for the JSP files.